# MySQL Database copy specific table to MySqlite with .sh script

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

this is `mysql2sqlite.sh`

```
# Skip other comments
/^\/\*/ { next }

# Print all `INSERT` lines. The single quotes are protected by another single quote.
/INSERT/ {
gsub( /\\\047/, "\047\047" )
gsub(/\\n/, "\n")
gsub(/\\r/, "\r")
gsub(/\\"/, "\"")
gsub(/\\\\/, "\\")
gsub(/\\\032/, "\032")
print
next
}

# Print the `CREATE` line as is and capture the table name.
/^CREATE/ {
print
if ( match( $0, /\"[^\"]+/ ) ) tableName = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
}

if (tableName == "tbl_driver") || (tableName == "tbl_vehicle"){

# Replace `FULLTEXT KEY` or any other `XXXXX KEY` except PRIMARY by `KEY`
/^ [^"]+KEY/ && !/^ PRIMARY KEY/ { gsub( /.+KEY/, " KEY" ) }

# Get rid of field lengths in KEY lines
/ KEY/ { gsub(/\([0-9]+\)/, "") }

# Print all fields definition lines except the `KEY` lines.
/^ / && !/^( KEY|\);)/ {
gsub( /AUTO_INCREMENT|auto_increment/, "" )
gsub( /(CHARACTER SET|character set) [^ ]+ /, "" )
gsub( /DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp/, "" )
gsub( /(COLLATE|collate) [^ ]+ /, "" )
gsub(/(ENUM|enum)[^)]+\)/, "text ")
gsub(/(SET|set)\([^)]+\)/, "text ")
gsub(/UNSIGNED|unsigned/, "")
if (prev) print prev ","
prev = $1
}

# `KEY` lines are extracted from the `CREATE` block and stored in array for later print
# in a separate `CREATE KEY` command. The index name is prefixed by the table name to
# avoid a sqlite error for duplicate index name.
/^( KEY|\);)/ {
if (prev) print prev
prev=""
if ($0 == ");"){
print
} else {
if ( match( $0, /\"[^"]+/ ) ) indexName = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
if ( match( $0, /\([^()]+/ ) ) indexKey = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
key[tableName]=key[tableName] "CREATE INDEX \"" tableName "_" indexName "\" ON \"" tableName "\" (" indexKey ");\n"
}
}

# Print all `KEY` creation lines.
END {
for (table in key) printf key[table]
print "END TRANSACTION;"
}
'
exit 0
} // closing for if (tableName == "tbl_driver") || (tableName == "tbl_vehicle")
```

and how i execute the sh with php

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('mysql2sqlite.sh -h host -u username -pmypasswrord db_shuttlebus | sqlite3 database.sqlite');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

mySQL database is having 3 table,
1)tbl_driver
2)tbl_vehicle
3)tbl_ticket

but, when copy to sqlite database i just want the 2 tables created, that is `tbl_driver` and `tbl_vehicle`.
so i have added in .sh with `if (tableName == "tbl_driver") || (tableName == "tbl_vehicle"){` if the table name is this two table name only create the table, but still not working ? why?

Comment: Define "not working". What errors do you get? Also you should be able to pass additional mysqldump command line options to that script which I assume you got from here - https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776  So you should be able to specify table names after the DB name in the command to get only the tables you want.

Comment: @MikeBrant `mysql2sqlite.sh -h host -u username -pmypasswrord db_shuttlebus tbl_driver,tbl_vehicle | sqlite3 database.sqlite` like this?

Comment: You do not separate table names with a comma, just with a space.